# show/hide menu items on client click for free Adminiziolite template

Tags: javascript, asp.net, menuitem

I've downloaded a web template of Adminiziolite. I am trying to create a show/hide menu items on client click. How can I do this?

```
<div id="aside" class="box">

    <div class="padding box">

        <!-- Logo (Max. width = 200px) -->
        <p id="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="tmp/logo.gif" alt="Our logo" title="Visit Site" /></a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /padding -->

    <ul class="box">
        <li><a href="OPDRegister.aspx">New Patient Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="OldPatientRegistration.aspx">Old Patient Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="DetailRegistration.aspx">Detail Patient Register</a></li>
        <li id="submenu-active"><a href="#">Report</a>
            <!-- Active -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">New Patient Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Old Patient Report</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Detail Patient Report</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to show/hide the menu items under the **Report** Section. On Client Click, the report items should be displayed, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide/show your sub menu adding the following JavaScript and inline CSS.

How does it work:

- Hide sub menu item report (using inline css `<ul style="display:none">`).
- Add an event listener (click) on your menu report.
- When User click on menu report, check variable `isMenuReportVisible`.
- If sub menu is not visible, make it visible, otherwise hide it.

```js
var btnHide = document.getElementById('btnHide'),
  btnShow = document.getElementById('btnShow'),
  reportMenu = document.querySelector('#submenu-active > ul'),
  menuReport = document.querySelector('#submenu-active'),
  isMenuReportVisible = false;
menuReport.addEventListener('click', function(even) {
  if (!isMenuReportVisible) {
    reportMenu.style.display = '';
    isMenuReportVisible = true;
  } else {
    reportMenu.style.display = 'none';
    isMenuReportVisible = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="aside" class="box">

  <div class="padding box">

    <!-- Logo (Max. width = 200px) -->
    <p id="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="tmp/logo.gif" alt="Our logo" title="Visit Site" /></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- /padding -->

  <ul class="box">
    <li><a href="OPDRegister.aspx">New Patient Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="OldPatientRegistration.aspx">Old Patient Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="DetailRegistration.aspx">Detail Patient Register</a></li>
    <li id="submenu-active"><a href="#">Report</a>
      <!-- Active -->
      <ul style="display:none">
        <li><a href="#">New Patient Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Old Patient Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Detail Patient Report</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You for the explanation.

Comment: @nischalinn I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li ul').hide()
  $("li").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="aside" class="box">
  <!-- /padding -->
  <ul class="box">
    <li><a href="#">New Patient Register</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Old Patient Register</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Detail Patient Register</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">New Patient Report</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Old Patient Report</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Detail Patient Report</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="submenu-active"><a href="#">Report</a>
      <!-- Active -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">New Patient Report</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Old Patient Report</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Detail Patient Report</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```